# An efficient way to parse the following string?

Tags: java

I'm getting the following response from a server in the form of a String...

`value_one=3342342&value_two=456344445&value_three=235333223`

What would be an efficient way to parse this? Everything I can come up with is pretty messy.

Comment: Split by `&` then split by `=`?

Comment: I'd like to send back the numerical values as part of a key value pair.

Comment: *"What would be an efficient way to parse this?"*  Asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you is often 'efficient'.  *"Everything I can come up with is pretty messy."*  Which leads to the question ["What Have You Tried?"](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: I've tried splitting but I thought there would be a better option.

Comment: @Skizit: how *"efficient"* do you want to be?  If you need to parse this in order to gain an edge on stock markets where every milliseconds count, then nothing beats an hardcoded state machine (besides an hardware hardcoded one ; )  ...   But then if every millisecond counted you probably wouldn't be using Java ; )

Comment: SyntaxT3rr0r, you'd be surprised how well Java does.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r I wanted something clean, fast and elegant. I know I'll be doing this a lot and so I realise that if it's done really poorly the time lost will add up on my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split on '&', loop, split on '='

```
public static Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query)
{
    String[] params = query.split("&");
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String param : params)
    {
        String name = param.split("=")[0];
        String value = param.split("=")[1];
        map.put(name, value);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Pardon for stating the obvious, but String.split() compiles regular expression every time. Besides, you are splitting the same string multiple times.

Comment: @Eugene, fair enough. I went for readability over premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to parse multiple strings, then repeatedly using `String.split()` method is not a good idea, because it would recompile split regular expression every time.

```
Pattern ampPattern = Pattern.compile("&");
Pattern eqPattern = Pattern.compile("=");
...

Map<String, Long> results = new HashMap<String, Long>();
for (String param : ampPattern.split(input)) {
  String[] pair = eqPattern.split(param);
  results.put(pair[0], Long.valueOf(pair[1]));
}
```

However for such a simple input string it will be even more efficient to not use regexps at all and avoid creation of temporary String arrays. Perhaps something like this:

```
Map<String, Long> results = new HashMap<String, Long>();
int start = 0;
int next;
do {
  next = input.indexOf('&', start);
  int end = next == -1 ? input.length() : next;
  int k = input.indexOf('=', start);
  results.put(input.substring(start, k), Long.valueOf(input.substring(k + 1, end)));
  start = next + 1;
} while (next > -1);
```

Of course, if you only parsing this string few times, such optimization may not worth it.

Comment: Upvote. To avoid using regex in such simple problems should always be awarded.

Answer (score 0):

First split the string on a "&".This will give you tokens each consisting of a name and value pair with a "=" separating them. So split them on "=" as required. Seems very simple to me unless you have other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

A naïve approach is to just use [String.split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String input = "value_one=3342342&value_two=456344445&value_three=235333223"
String[] rawAttrs = input.split("&");

// Split each attribute into pairs - assume some sort of Pair class exists
List<Pair<String, String>> attributes = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
for (String rawAttr : rawAttrs) {
    String[] parts = rawAttrs.split("=");
    attributes.add(new Pair<String, String>(parts[0], parts[1]);
}
```

This approach doesn't handle malformed entries well - but more importantly, it doesn't consider what happens if part of the attribute values includes an `=` or `&` character.  Are these backslash-escaped?  Are they URL-encoded?  Is there some other way that they would be embedded?

If you can guarantee that the values are integers then this won't be a problem, but you need to ensure that all the bases are covered.

Comment: See my comment about String.split() in another answer.